# Swiper-slide is in full width rather than specified width

Tags: html, css, swiper.js

I was following one tutorial about making a testimonial slider with Swiper.js and I encountered a problem.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="layer"></div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.</p>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.testimonials {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    width: 350px;
    min-height: 350px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

The problem here is that when executed, it returns to full width rather than the specified width. Is there a quick fix?

Comment: Screenshots, a link of a hosted page or a live code demo would help us see your issue better and come up with an answer.

Comment: @barhatsor, I don't have the file but I've tried to recreate the same demo from [this video](https://youtu.be/5wMGPptPRjQ). Idk why but the code worked on him than mine.